# Linux PDF reader which handle speaker notes

Tags: linux, pdf, ubuntu, presentation

I've tried several versions (adobe, evince and foxit) but no one seems to handle speaker notes in pdf presentations.

Edit: for example Google drive presentations or microsoft office powerpoint allow to insert speaker notes that are displayed in separated window and which can, for example, be dragged to the laptop screen while the main presentation is displayed in the datashow screen, both are bounded to each other, when one passes to a new slide in the big screen, its corresponding notes are displayed on the laptop screen.

Comment: What do you mean with Speaker notes? Are you referring to text (or other) annotations? Also: what do you mean by 'handle'? Do you want to show them? Extract them? The question needs clarifying!

Comment: I don't think what you call "speaker notes" are possible in PDF.

Comment: Even though I don't think this link solves it, it may help someone http://superuser.com/questions/339404/solutions-for-presenting-pdf-slides-with-presenter-notes-on-second-display